# Pyparsing issue with 3.0 works with 2.4 pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

```
      """
        method to parse filter string
        """

        prop = pp.WordStart(pp.alphas) + pp.Word(pp.alphanums +
                                                 "_").setResultsName("prop")
        value = (pp.QuotedString("'") | pp.QuotedString('"') | pp.Word(
            pp.printables, excludeChars=",")).setResultsName("value")
        types_ = pp.oneOf("re eq ne gt ge lt le").setResultsName("types")
        flags = pp.oneOf("C I").setResultsName("flags")
        comma = pp.Literal(',')
        quote = (pp.Literal("'") | pp.Literal('"')).setResultsName("quote")

        type_exp = pp.Group(pp.Literal("type") + pp.Literal(
            "=") + quote + types_ + quote).setResultsName("type_exp")
        flag_exp = pp.Group(pp.Literal("flag") + pp.Literal(
            "=") + quote + flags + quote).setResultsName("flag_exp")

        semi_expression = pp.Forward()
        semi_expression << pp.Group(pp.Literal("(") +
                                    prop + comma + value +
                                    pp.Optional(comma + type_exp) +
                                    pp.Optional(comma + flag_exp) +
                                    pp.Literal(")")
                                    ).setParseAction(
            self.parse_filter_obj).setResultsName("semi_expression")

        expr = pp.Forward()
        expr << pp.infixNotation(semi_expression, [
            ("not", 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, self.not_operator),
            ("and", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, self.and_operator),
            ("or", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, self.or_operator)
        ])        
       result = expr.parseString(filter_str)
```

This is working fine with pyparsing 2.4.7, but doesn't work with latest pyparsing version.
the example input given is:

```
  filter_str = 'not (dn,"org-root/ls-C1_B1", type="eq")'
```

This results in exception with latest pyparsing module 3.0.6.

```
pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected 'or' term, found 'dn'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6).
```

I tried different ways to solve this, but not getting rid of this exception. Let me know if there is any obvious mistake in this approach.

Comment: To provide more context: not_operator is static method defined for the class
`
   @staticmethod
     def not_operator(toks):
         not_filter = NotFilter()
         for op_filter in toks[0][1:]:
             not_filter.child_add(op_filter)
         return not_filter
`

Comment: if you nave new information then better put in question, not in comments. It will be more readable in question and more people will see it. People may not read comments.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch! This is a bug in the PEP8-compatibility logic in pyparsing 3.0, where I was adding support for the argument to `WordStart` supporting both `wordChars` and `word_chars`.  I will have it fixed in the next release. In the meantime, you can work around the bug by changing `Word(pp.alphas)` to `Word(word_chars=pp.alphas)`.

A couple of other comments on your parser:

- It isn't necessary to define `semi_expression` or `expr` using pyparsing `Forward`s. `semi_expression` is not a recursive expression, and the recursion in `expr` is already taken care of in the `infixNotation` method.
- Since part of your grammar is a freely defined property name, to avoid potential ambiguity in parsing, I would define all of the literals in your grammar that would also match as a `prop` using `pp.Keyword` (change `pp.Literal("type")` to `pp.Keyword("type")`, for instance, and your operators "not", "and", and "or").

These comments aren't related to the problem you are seeing, and your grammar will work fine without these changes. They are just some optional refinements you may choose to make to your parser code.

Comment: This is Issue #346 in the pyparsing GitHub repo. https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues/346

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcG, for quickly checking on the issue, finding the root cause and providing workaround/fix for the same. Really appreciate it.
The workarond you provided didn't work exactly as it is, but after checking the fix you did on github, I was able to workaround the issue by providing both word_chars and wordChars arguments. ie Replace
`WordStart(pp.alphas)` with `WordStart(word_chars=pp.alphas, pp.wordChars=pp.alphas)`. 
I would like to thank you for the suggestion of using Keyword.

Comment: Fixed in release 3.0.7